# How to create a left vertical line between subheadings

Tags: code, cv

[image: milstones path]

How do I create the above graphic at beginning of every subheading?

Comment: could you kindly add the corresponding TEX syntax of what you have attempted -so that retyping of data is not required

Comment: I would do the whole thing as a tikzpicure.  Alternatively, one could locate the text using tikzmarks.

Comment: I would probably place tikzmarks to the subheadings and then connect them using a "remember picture, overlay" construct.